# Can I "overload" topic names in ROS? (Different versions by datatype)

Tags: ros, topic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I advertise a topic with one name and two versions depending on the data type being transferred?

Specifically, the pointcloud_throttle node is hardcoded to a depth-only pointcloud, and I'm going to extend it to a RGB cloud as well. I want to know if i can just

pub_ = nh.advertise("cloud_out", 10);

pub_ = nh.advertise("cloud_out", 10);

Or if i need to come up with a separate topic name, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9713/can-i-%22overload%22-topic-names-in-ros?-(different-versions-by-datatype)/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-12**:
woops, yup, edited.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-12**:
Do you mean topic names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you cannot overload topics.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4